# Rendering of Element in CakePHP Controller throws Missing View error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I am trying to render a view inside a controller and load it using ajax.

It works fine in my local system but in the server it throws an error:

```
Error: The view for MyController::myView() was not found.
```

Here is my code

**Controller**:

```
public function creativeForms(){
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $createdForm = '';
    if(!empty($this->request->data['id'])){
        $request = array();
        $requestFields = array();
        if(isset($this->request->data['req_id']) && !empty($this->request->data['req_id'])) {
            App::import('Model', 'RequestField');
            $RequestField  = new RequestField();
            $request = $RequestField->find('list',array('fields'=>array('RequestField.form_field_id','RequestField.value'),'conditions'=>array('RequestField.request_id'=>$this->request->data['req_id'])));
            $requestFields = $RequestField->find('list',array('fields'=>array('RequestField.form_field_id','RequestField.id'),'conditions'=>array('RequestField.request_id'=>$this->request->data['req_id'])));
        }

        $form  = $this->FormField->Form->findByid($this->request->data['id']);
        $createdForm = $this->createForm($form,$request,$requestFields);
    }

    echo $createdForm;
    exit;
}

public function createForm($form , $data= NULL,$dataMap=array()){
    $createForm ='';

    foreach($form['FormField'] as $FormField){
        $this->set('FormField',$FormField);
        $this->set('data',$data);
        $this->set('dataMap',$dataMap);
        switch ($FormField['field_type']){
            case 'textbox':
                $createForm .= $this->render('../elements/fields/textbox');
            break;

            case 'textarea':
                $createForm .= $this->render('../elements/fields/textarea');
            break;

            case 'radio':
                $createForm .= $this->render('../elements/fields/radio');
            break;

            case 'checkbox':
                $createForm .= $this->render('../elements/fields/checkbox');
            break;

            case 'file':
                $createForm .= $this->render('../elements/fields/upload');
            break;

            case 'datefield':
                $createForm .= $this->render('../elements/fields/datefield');
            break;

            case 'select':
                $createForm .= $this->render('../elements/fields/select');
            break;
        }
    }

    return $createForm;
}
```

**`datefield.ctp`**

```
    $field  =     $this->form->hidden('RequestField.'.$FormField['id'].'.type',
    array('value'=>'datefield')); 
    $required = '';
    if($FormField['field_required']){ 
      $required = ' required';
    }
    if(isset($data[$FormField['id']])){
       $field .=    $this->form->hidden('RequestField.'.$FormField['id'].'.id',
       array('value'=>$dataMap[$FormField['id']])); 
    $field .=  $this->Form->input('RequestField.'.$FormField['id'].'.value',
     array('value'=>$data[$FormField['id']],'type'=>'text',
    'required'=>$FormField['field_required'],
    'label'=>$FormField['field_label'],'class'=>'form-control default date-picker',
    'div'=>array('class'=>'form-group'.$required)));
    } else {
    $field .=   $this->Form->input('RequestField.'.$FormField['id'].'.value',
   array('type'=>'text','required'=>$FormField['field_required'],
   'label'=>$FormField['field_label'],'class'=>'form-control default-date-picker',
   'div'=>array('class'=>'form-group'.$required)));
   }
   echo $field;
```

I have tried solving it with things like:

```
$view = new View($this, false);
$view->set(compact('foo', 'bar')); // set variables
$view->viewPath = 'elements'; // render an element
$html = $view->render('message');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your code you are referencing folder:

```
app/View/elements
```

when it should be

```
app/View/Elements
```

The first line works on Windows (as it uses a case-insensitive file and directory naming convention), but won't work on Unix-like OSes.

Try changing your code to:

```
$this->viewPath = 'Elements';
$this->render('fields/upload');
$this->render('fields/checkbox');
//and so on
```

Comment: Thanks Inigo it solved the issue

One more thing i had made wrong i called form instead of Form. Any way fixed that now :)